# Select Rows and Flag Column if value found

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

i need help for creating a query

Current situation:

The output table contains Ids and levels. Each Id can appear several times.

Problem:

Now I want to know if level 1 appears for an id, if so I want to mark it as number 1. If an Id has only level 2 or zero just mark it as number 0.

The output can be taken from the table below.

[image: data basis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when level = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: @FlEx . . . The `case` returns `1` only when `level` has a value of `1`.  The `max()` summarizes that over all rows for a given `id`.